# Javascript with simple file IO using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've written a simple game in an HTML file and javascript script. It presents the user with choices and reacts to them. I'd like to log those choices in a text file, but have discovered that Javascript isn't really suited for those sorts of file operations. So I've tried to learn node.js and read a bunch of tutorials, but those jump into routes, http servers and other complex (to me) topics; all I need is to serve a single webpage, with the node.js file IO. Can anyone direct me to an example or tutorial that might work for me?

Comment: Why a text file if you're trying to target client-side only? Have you considered local storage of some sort?

Comment: Node.js is a javascript interpreter. Just like Firefox or IE or Chrome or Safari. It doesn't run on your browser. It runs on your PC (just like Firefox etc.). The intention is to make Javascript able to run on servers just like other languages such as Ruby, Perl and Python. So APIs available on Node aren't available in Firefox or IE unless Firefox developers decide to implement them (they won't, it's a security risk for browsers).